# Access forbidden Error 403 web service using json and cURL

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services, curl

I have to make a web service. Therefore I referred some tutorials in the internet and came up with the following codes

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="http://localhost:81/my%20web%20service/webservice" method="get">
        Table name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="s" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

webservice.php

```
<?php

include('connectdb.php');

$something = $_POST['s'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $something";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$myArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
        echo "name: " . $row["name"]. " - town: " . $row["town"]. " - telephone: " . $row["telephone"]. "<br>";
    }
    //$data = json_encode($myArray);
    //var_dump($data);

    $url = 'http://localhost:81/my%20web%20service/show%details.php';
    $ch=curl_init($url);
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $string = http_build_query($myArray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    $applist = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
//$result->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

connectdb.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "webservice_trial";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else{
    echo "connection successful.<br>";
}

?>
```

Now what I want to do is to make data display on another page.
i.e. I want to transfer data from webservice.php to another page (show details.php) from json format.

show details.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Show details page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    print_r($_POST['data']);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

how i can redirect the json string from web service to the show details.php

what i get is this

```
connection successful.
name: hilton - town: colombo - telephone: 774933705
name: galadari - town: colombo - telephone: 112894143
name: mt. lavinia - town: mt. lavinia - telephone: 773580324
string(257) "[{"name":"hilton","town":"colombo","telephone":"774933705","description":"excellent"},{"name":"galadari","town":"colombo","telephone":"112894143","description":"best"},{"name":"mt. lavinia","town":"mt. lavinia","telephone":"773580324","description":"good"}]"
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-  protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
```

Comment: are you working on localhost or web hosting

Comment: im working with localhost (xampp)

Comment: Check your hosts file, Apache2 config file and virtual host file

Comment: @NimmiRashinika, you have issue in your query :
`
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $something";` , `$something` is not your table name I guess

Comment: @ Ms. Nehal it works i checked already

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code below, add it in your virtual host config

```
<Directory "E:/MyProjects/projectname/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

I fixed the same issue by this way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Nimmi Rashinika,

--> First, you used GET method in form and get data using $_POST. I think here you could not get any response.
--> Second think you have init curl twise time , so please remove that code.

Below my code , that working fine..

**Index.php**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="http://localhost/csvToExcle/sof35545870/webservice/webservice.php" method="get">
    Table name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="s" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**connection.php**

```html
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "telecom";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else{
    echo "connection successful.<br>";
}
?>
```

**webservice.php**

```html
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); include('connection.php');
$something = $_GET['s'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $something";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$myArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
        echo "auth_key: " . $row["auth_key"]. " - token: " . $row["token"]. " - telephone: " . $row["caller_id_caller"]. "<br>";
    }

    $url = 'http://localhost/csvToExcle/sof35545870/showDetails.php';
    $string = http_build_query($myArray);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    $applist = curl_exec($ch);

    if($applist === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**showDetails.php**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Show details page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    print_r($_POST);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```